# Is it possible to alter the structure of DataFrame A to look like that of DataFrame B?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: DATA FRAME A]

[image: DATA FRAME B]

I've tried using `stack` and `unstack`, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Code so far:

```
#Pull 'relevant data' about the selected stocks.

price_data_close = web.get_data_yahoo(potential_portfolio,
                           start = '2014-01-01',
                           end = '2018-05-31')['Close']   

price_data = web.get_data_yahoo(potential_portfolio,
                           start = '2014-01-01',
                           end = '2018-05-31')   

df = pd.DataFrame(price_data)
print(df)

df_closing = pd.DataFrame(price_data_close)
print(df_closing)
```

(`potential_portfolio` is an array of ticker/stock symbols)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to swap the column levels (`Symbols`/`Adjusted`), so you can use [**`swaplevel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [**`sort_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) along `axis=1`.

Assuming "DataFrame A" is called `df_a`:

```py
df_a = df_a.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

If that's not what you're asking, please edit your question with more details.

Comment: Worked, much appreciated!